# BoxLayout for a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, checkboxlist

Could you help me understand what is going on here. I consulted Javadoc: JFrame has setLayout method. So, what sharing error springs out is a mystery to me.

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    public View(){

        // LayoutManager for the whole frame.
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    }
}
```

### Result

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkContainer(BoxLayout.java:465)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.invalidateLayout(BoxLayout.java:249)
    at java.awt.Container.invalidate(Container.java:1583)
    at java.awt.Component.invalidateIfValid(Component.java:2957)
    at java.awt.Container.setLayout(Container.java:1484)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.setLayout(JFrame.java:605)
    at View.<init>(View.java:16)
    at Init.main(Init.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761341/boxlayout-cant-be-shared-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one on [JFrame#getContentPane()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

```
this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Read more [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

---

All the components are added in `JFrame's` content pane.

Read more [Adding Components to the Content Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane)

Here is the pictorial representation how JFrame looks like

[image]

---

#### EDIT

From comments:

> Well, not clear anyway. I analyze it like this: BoxLayout class needs to know it target. JFrame has setLayoutt method and needs to know its layout.

`this.setLayout(manager)` internally calls `getContentPane().setLayout(manager);`

The below line

```
this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

is converted to below line that is not correct.

```
this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

For more detail have a look at [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JFrame.java#JFrame.setLayout%28java.awt.LayoutManager%29)

Comment: Working. But I can't understand anything. Could you clarify what exactly did I share?

Comment: Well, not clear anyway. I analyze it like this: BoxLayout class needs to know it target. JFrame has setLayoutt method and needs to know its layout. In all examples I've seen objects invoking setLayout and the target to BoxLayout are the same. Like this: listPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); this is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html Well,  in this light I can't still see the reason why I should getContentPane.

Comment: `this.setLayout()` internally calls `this.getContentPane().setLayout()` that is applying layout on content pane on which JFrame adds the component.

Comment: Here is [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JFrame.java#JFrame.setLayout%28java.awt.LayoutManager%29) and I hope now its clear to you.